# Alternatives to QGIS Resource Sharing Plugin for QGIS 3.4.0

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have been trying to install the QGIS Resource Sharing Plugin in QGIS version 3.4.0. but it gives me the error message that this plugin is incompatible for all version above 2.99.

Does anybody know other similar packages? I wanted to install the plugin to import icons from png / svg format.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is ''only'' a way to automatically load ressources. At present time the alternative for QGIS 3 would be to manually load the same ressource.

You may have a look at the different repositories and download what you need (sorry for using screen capture no time to retype...)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but just in case someone else has the same problem. An experimental version that is compatible with QGIS version 3.4.0 has been added as of Dec. 4, 2018, 9:44 a.m. However, I couldn't find it in the plugin manager (even with experimental plugins enabled), so I had to install it manually.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_resource_sharing/version/0.6.0/

Comment: Version 0.6.0 is available now (and has been for some time) in the *Plugin Manager* if you have checked "Show also experimental plugins" in the *Plugin Manager* settings.

Answer (score 1):

The *Resource Sharing* plugin works with QGIS 3, and is no longer experimental. It can be installed using the QGIS *Plugin Manager* through the official QGIS plugin site (http://plugins.qgis.org). Support for R scripts and Processing models was added recently, and SVGs, symbols (XML files), layer styles (QML files) and *Processing scripts have been supported for a long time. See http://qgis-contribution.github.io/QGIS-ResourceSharing for more information.

Happy sharing!